# Transferring files from Windows to HP NonStop using FTE

Tags: ftp, websphere-mq-fte

I have to move files using FTE v7.5 from Windows Systems to HP NonStop [Tadem] servers and vice versa. Since the latest version of MQ supported for Tandem is MQv5.3 which do not have the FTE I cannot install FTE client edition and configure agents in them. Is there any support pacs which can make this possible.?? Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at this time.  One solution is to deliver/retrieve the files on a shared drive to which the HP server has access.  Another is to use the FTE Protocol Bridge agent to deliver/retrieve files using the HP FTP server as an endpoint.

Responding to the comments, this is one way to use the FTE Protocol Bridge to send files to an HP-Non-Stop server that hosts an FTP server.   Note that both FTE agents talk to the same QMgr on Windows.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @T.Rob I was curious about the FTE Protocol Bridge agent. So my understanding is this to work a FTE Protocol Bridge agent has to be defined in the Windows Server QMgr and on the Tandem Server there has to be HP FTP Server Program running.

Comment: The entire path is that there's an FTE agent at one end where files are retrieved/delivered and a protocol bridge at the QMgr server.  The protocol bridge talks over one of several protocols to an FTP server somewhere to retrieve or deliver files.  The primary requirement is that the protocol bridge must reside on the server where the QMgr lives.  That's OK though because the file contents are never cached there except the few chunks that are in WMQ messages at any one time, and these can be encrypted if that's an issue.

Comment: Thanks again! @T.Rob I think I am slightly confused here. How can I get an FTE Agent installed in HP Nonstop server because the MQ v5.3 installed in it does not support that command. I have to send/retrieve files back and forth Windows Server and Tandem Server.

Comment: Thanks! I was working on a Visio for this and you already provided one!! This explains well!

Comment: This works fine now! I am able to do a PUT and GET operation from a Windows Server Application to HP NonStop Server using fteCreateTransfer. How is the reverse possible?? If an application connected to HP NonStop Server has to do a PUT operation I cannot make use of fteCreateTransfer or cannot define fteAgents??

Comment: You can have the bridge agent monitor one or more directories on the HP server.  When a file shows up, it is automagically moved.  Where it gets moved to is a function of how you set up the monitoring.

Comment: How is that possible?The infocenter says "The fteCreateMonitor command is not supported on protocol bridge agents."

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit of an oversimplification. You'd need to have a scheduler or other method to repeatedly drive an inbound file transfer.  Probably a good topic for a separate question.  If you post, Ill see if I can get one of the devs or ISSW consultants to respond.

Comment: Thanks! Sure I will post a separate question!